# Root to the Minimal

Tags: shell, root

I am building a script to automate and minimize access to root. I am going to try do it via SSH. I am currently having an issue using `sed` to replace UID and GID 0 shell to `/sbin/nologin`.

Why am I doing this? This disables root on `login`, `gdm`, `kdm`, `su`, `ssh`, `scp`, `sftp`. I am trying to execute root privilege only via `sudo`. If you know any suggestion on minimizing root access, please also suggest.

This is the current issue:

```
grep :0:0: /etc/passwd | sudo sed 's_/bin/bash_/sbin/nologin_' /etc/passwd
```

What is currently doing is replacing all `/bin/bash` to `/sbin/nologin`.

Comment: have you tried `usermod --expiredate 1 root` ? This should disable the root account.

Answer (score 2):

*1. get a acount which is a sudoer*

```
su -
echo '<YOU>  ALL=(ALL:ALL)  ALL'>>/etc/sudoers
exit
```

*2. disable the root account*

```
sudo usermod --expiredate 1 root
```

*3. test it*

```
$ su -
Password: <correct password>
Your account is expired.
```

Tested on Debian GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

what

```
grep :0:0: /etc/passwd | sudo sed 's_/bin/bash_/sbin/nologin_' /etc/passwd
```

do ?

- `grep :0:0: /etc/passwd` search for line(s ?) with uid/gid being 0, this usualy give the line with root, this line is feeded to STDOUT (standard output )
- `|` output from grep is feed to sudo sed which is discarded due to a file being specified in command line.
- `sed 's_/bin/bash_/sbin/nologin_' /etc/passwd` this replace bash by nologin from /etc/passwd to STDOUT, /etc/passwd is left unchanged.

have you simply try .. ?

```
sudo sed -i '/:0:0:/s_/bin/bash_/sbin/nologin_' /etc/passwd
```